# VS 2017 (Ctrl+R) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> was globally mapped to Edit.NavigateTo. In VS 2017 Community, they've renamed this to Edit.GoToAll, which <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is globally mapped to. But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in C# editor, I get "(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord..." and the dialog does not open.

What is hijacking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Globally mapped to edit.navigate? Not in mine.

Comment: Tools > Customize > Keyboard > Press shortcut keys.  Press Ctrl+R and the combobox below it shows a list of all the shortcuts that use it.  Refactor on my machine but I don't use the default layout.  Also the dialog you can use to reorganize them.

Comment: Yes! That helped me find what was blocking Ctrl+R. It's possible I chose this setting myself in VS 2015 since some past IDE (FlashDevelop?) used it for "find references".

Answer (score 3):

Aah, didn't notice that shortcuts in use was a dropdown with multiple values - thank you Hans Passant. Looks like Edit.ViewWhiteSpace defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and that was making <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> not work at all. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

I had a massive problem with chords where I couldn't even use "command Z" anymore. The way I was able to fix my chords issue was by editing the JSON file by following:

1. settings
2. preferences
3. keyboard shortcuts
4. while in keyboard shortcuts on the top right you will see an icon that looks like a file with an arrow on it. Click this. It will take you into keybindings.json.
   Here you can view all chords, add, edit and delete chords. I removed my command z chord and everything was back to normal.